# Get clicked button id with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to get my generated button id when I click it, to select and manipulate own parent div.

`$(this).attr("id")` and `this.id` are returning undefined or k.fn.init.

What am I missing, please?

JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// functions

    let taskCounter = 0;

    let addOne = () => {
        let userStr = document.getElementById("userText").value;
        let nextItem = taskCounter;
        $("#toDoList ul").append('<div class="item-'+nextItem+'"><li>'+userStr+'</li><input id="btn-'+nextItem+'" type="button" value="Complete Task" onclick="taskDone()"></div>');
        taskCounter = taskCounter + 1
    }

    let taskDone = () => {
        let selectTest = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(selectTest);
        return selectTest;

    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="userText" type="text" placeholder="Enter Task Here">
        <input id="addToList" type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addOne()">
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <div id="toDoList">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>Done</h2>
        <div id="DoneList">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the only valid child element for a `ul` element is an `li` element. The code above is appending a `div`.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the element in params:

```js
// functions

let taskCounter = 0;

let addOne = () => {
  let userStr = document.getElementById("userText").value;
  let nextItem = taskCounter;
  $("#toDoList ul").append('<div class="item-' + nextItem + '"><li>' + userStr + '</li><input id="btn-' + nextItem + '" type="button" value="Complete Task" onclick="taskDone(this)"></div>');
  taskCounter = taskCounter + 1
}

function taskDone(el) {
  let selectTest = el.getAttribute("id")
  console.log(selectTest);
  //return selectTest;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input id="userText" type="text" placeholder="Enter Task Here">
  <input id="addToList" type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addOne()">
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <div id="toDoList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2>Done</h2>
  <div id="DoneList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's possible, but the problem is just that OP is using an arrow function, which doesn't retain the context of `this`.

Comment: Better just to attach the event handler with jQuery rather than using an attribute at all, I should think...

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular function definition instead of an arrow function. An arrow function changes the context of `this`. So with `let taskDone = () => {...}` and you try to access `this`, it's not referring to the element you clicked. Instead, try `let taskDone = function () {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use HTML attributes to attach event handlers to HTML elements. Instead, use jQuery's own event attachment mechanism, `on`. Also, don't bury information by encoding it into IDs; just use a `data-` attribute. Note that the code below does not solve the problem that it introduces invalid HTML; namely, a `ul` element can only have `li` elements as children, not `div` elements.

```js
// functions

let taskCounter = 0;

let addOne = () => {
  let userStr = document.getElementById("userText").value;
  let nextItem = taskCounter;
  $("#toDoList ul").append('<div class="item-' + nextItem + '"><li>' + userStr + '</li><input id="btn-' + nextItem + '" type="button" value="Complete Task" data-index="' + nextItem + '" class="done"></div>');
  taskCounter = taskCounter + 1
}

function taskDone() {
  let selectTest = this.getAttribute("data-index");
  console.log(selectTest);
  //return selectTest;
}

$("#addToList").on("click", addOne);
$(document).on("click", ".done", taskDone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input id="userText" type="text" placeholder="Enter Task Here">
  <input id="addToList" type="button" value="Add Task">
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <div id="toDoList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2>Done</h2>
  <div id="DoneList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```